# How can I dismiss a modal segue then perform push segue to new view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, segue

I'm trying to perform a `push segue` from a `navigation controller`, after dismissing a `modal` that was previously presented over the `navigation controller`.

Inside modal (`UIViewController`):

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    var searchNav = SearchNavigationController()
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {searchNav.goToNextView()})
    return true
}
```

Inside `SearchNavigationController`:

```
func goToNextView() {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("searchNavigationToNextView", sender: self)
}
```

The issue is that when I hit return, I get this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver
>   () has no segue with
>   identifier 'searchNavigationToNextView''

The segue is present in my `storyboard`, going from the `UINavigationController` to the `next view`.

[image]

EDIT: tried this, where _sender is declared in SingleSearchViewcontroller as var _sender = self and it did not work.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "searchNavigationToSingleSearch" {
            let singleVC = segue.destinationViewController as! SingleSearchViewController

            singleVC._sender = self
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to call the segue from the appropriate controller that represents its origin. In this case you should probably call the segue on self and not the nav controller

Comment: You can't cal  a segue from UINavigationController, you should call it from the top controller of UINavigationController

Comment: @jinhualiao that makes sense, but I just tried it and got the same error. could it have something to do with the fact that the error has an extra ' in it? Although that is not in my code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your code as,

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    var searchNav = SearchNavigationController()
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {self.presentingViewController.goToNextView()})
    return true
}
```

Comment: I think you are correct, but I'm not sure how to pass the delegate to the modal view controller. I tried something like the code I added above in prepareforsegue but it cannot assign a value of type SearchNavigationController to SingleSearchViewController

Comment: Do I have to do some sort of assignment to indicate this view's presentingViewController? When I try that code it does not let me access self.presentingViewController's methods

Comment: It does not allow me to autocomplete the function name and the error is  Cannot invoke 'dismissViewControllerAnimated' with an argument list of type '(Bool, completion: () -> _)'

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue that mattgabor had, and i tried Ashish's solution but it didn't work for me.

The problem i had in my code was that inside the completion block of "dismissViewControllerAnimated()", the propery "self.presentingViewController" was already nil when i wanted to call the method from my previous viewController that performed the push (the method "goToNextView()" in this example)

So my solution was just to create a variable to hold the previous viewController before calling "dismissViewControllerAnimated()". Using the current example, it would look like this:

```
    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if let searchNav = self.presentingViewController as? SearchNavigationController {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true) {
            searchNav.goToNextView()
        }
    }
    return true
 }
```