# Present a view controller, dismiss it and present a different one in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, presentviewcontroller

I have a root view controller that has a button that when the user pushes it, another view controller is presented.

This second controller has a dismiss option that just comes back to the root view controller and a button that when the user touches it dismisses the current view controller so it goes back to the root view controller for a second and presents another one.

Going to the first controller I use:

```
let vc = FirstController()
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And when in the other view controller I select the button that only dismisses I do this.

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

So for the second controller that needs to dismiss and present another one I have tried the following:

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
    let vc = SecondController()
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
})
```

But I get an error:

> Warning: Attempt to present <UINavigationController: 0xa40c790> on <IIViewDeckController: 0xa843000> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Answer (score 99, accepted):

The error occurs because you are trying to present SecondController from FirstController after you have dismissed FirstController. This doesn't work:

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
    let vc = SecondController()

    // 'self' refers to FirstController, but you have just dismissed
    //  FirstController! It's no longer in the view hierarchy!
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
})
```

This problem is very similar to a question I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43527014/performing-segue-after-sender-view-controller-is-dismissed/43533019#43533019) yesterday.

Modified for your scenario, I would suggest this:

```
weak var pvc = self.presentingViewController

self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
    let vc = SecondController()
    pvc?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
})
```

Comment: Hey Mike, I get a red flag with "loadMissing argument for parameter 'coder' in call" next to SecondController() I don't know what its expecting.

Comment: How we can push new controller without getting a flicker / blink in the UI, how can we make the transition smooth?

Comment: Is this code producing flicker / blink? If so, can you post a new question? Thanks.

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to work in my case. I've to use protocol.

Comment: @AmanGangurde Did you post a question for eliminating the flicker?

Comment: Dude, you just made my day with this code! Thank you!!

Comment: Simple and magnificent...

Answer (score 0):

Only the presenting view controller (Root) can dismiss its presented view controller (First or Second).
So you need to call `dismiss(animated:completion:)` inside the Root view controller's class, not inside any other one:

```swift
class RootViewController: UIViewController {
  func buttonTapped() {
    let vc = FirstViewController()
    vc.delegate = self
    present(vc, animated: true)
  }
}

extension RootViewController: FirstViewControllerDelegate {
  func firstDidComplete() {
    dismiss(animated: true) {
      let vc = SecondViewController()
      vc.delegate = self
      present(vc, animated: true)
    }
  }
}

extension RootViewController: SecondViewControllerDelegate {
  func secondDidComplete() {
    dismiss(animated: true) {
      let vc = ThirdViewController()
      present(vc, animated: true)
    }
  }
}

// and so on
```

If FirstViewController presents other view controller and you want its dismissal animation, implement FirstViewController as follows:

```swift
extension FirstViewController: OtherViewControllerDelegate {
  func otherDidComplete() {
    dismiss(animated: true) {
      self.delegate?.firstDidComplete()
    }
  }
}
```