# How to present another view controller after dismiss from navigation controller in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

How to present another view controller after dismiss from navigation controller in swift ?

I am using Navigation controller.

ViewController1.swift

```
func pushTo(viewController: UIViewController) {
        let showLocalPwd = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LocalPwdVC") as! LocalPwdVC
        self.navigationController?.present(showLocalPwd, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

ViewController2.swift

```
    @IBAction func btnVerify(_ sender: Any)
    {
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
                 let vc = self.storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DataVC") as! DataVC
            self.navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
            })
    }
```

After dismissing the View Controller, it will not goes to next viewcontroller i.e. DataVC

Comment: post your current code please

Comment: Well you need to use delegate method to achieve this

Comment: I added the code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43566414/present-a-controller-dismiss-it-and-present-a-different-one-in-swift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to present the view controller then create a protocol in your dismissViewController

```
protocol dismissViewController {
func presentCompletedViewController()
 }
// Then create a delegate 
   var delegate = dismissViewController? = nil
// If you are using action to dismiss your ViewController then call delegate

     @IBAction func YourButton(_ sender: Any) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true) {
        self.delegate!.presentCompletedViewController()
    }
}

//And then call this in your main or homeViewController
  class HomeViewController: UIViewController, dismissViewController {
 func presentCompletedViewController(){
// enter code to present view controller
 }
 // And at last don't forget to call delegate
    yourVc.delegate = self
    you need to call this delegate in which you are presenting your dismissViewController
```

Comment: where you getting the problem

Comment: you need to call this function in which your calling your dismiss view controller  let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "dismissVC") as! dismissViewController
            vc.delegate = self

Comment: self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
                    self.delegate!.presentVisitorDataVC()
                }) .  .... It shows "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value".

Comment: its because your are not calling delegate method go to your firstcontroller from which you called the dismiss view controller and add this in your push segue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168056/discussion-between-v-rohit-and-creative-study).