# Protocol doesn't get read in swift xcode project

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

i have a `UITableview` that has unique cells, 
each cell has it's own class and they have actions that i want to connect to my main `UITableviewcontroller`

I attach a protocol and open it in the tableviewcontroller 
but it doesn't get read

how could I initialise it or what am I doing wrong ?

**here is my cell class :**

```
import UIKit

class AddFaxHeadlineTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var delegate: AddFaxHeadlineProtocol?

    @IBOutlet weak var addButton: UIButton!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    @IBAction func onAddFaxNumberPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.faxButtonPressed()

    }

}


protocol AddFaxHeadlineProtocol{
    func faxButtonPressed()
}
```

and in my tableviewcontroller I extend the protocol:

```
class SummaryMainTableViewController: UITableViewController, AddFaxHeadlineProtocol, AddEmailHeadlineProtocol {
```

but the function itself never gets read:

```
func faxButtonPressed() {

        var indexToInsert = 0

        for forIndex in 0..<sectionsData.count {
            // render the tick mark each minute (60 times)
            if (sectionsData[forIndex] == "addFaxHeadline") {
                indexToInsert = forIndex + 1
            }

        }


        sectionsData.insert("addNewFax", at: indexToInsert)
        mainTableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48961356/5857254

Answer (score 5):

You need to call:

```
cell.delegate = self
```

In your `cellForRowAtIndex` method

This is the common mistake done in protocols and delegates to forget to call **delegate**.

Here are few examples you can check all have missing is calling delegate:-

[Swift delegate beetween two VC without segue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51281372/swift-delegate-beetween-two-vc-without-segue/51287027#51287027)

[Delegate seems to not be working, according to the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52327377/delegate-seems-to-not-be-working-according-to-the-console/52327562#52327562)

[How to present another view controller after dismiss from navigation controller in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49613480/how-to-present-another-view-controller-after-dismiss-from-navigation-controller/49613695#49613695)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to go inside the vc without protocols

```
let cell = ///

cell.addButton.tag = indexPath.row

cell.addButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

}

@objc func buttonTapped(_ sender:UIButton) {

    print(sender.tag)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check that you are doing this:

```
cell.delegate = self (It's required)
```

Then improve your line of code like below. Because you will not set delegate then by calling this delegate method directly will get crashed.

```
@IBAction func onAddFaxNumberPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    if let delegateObject = delegate {
        delegateObject.faxButtonPressed()
    }
}
```

Second, 
In this line, delegateObject.faxButtonPressed(), you will need to send some parameter to identify that will cell is clicked. So you can pass here button tag or you can pass cell also.