# Previous ViewController stays active

Tags: swift

I have one ViewController, I switch to it programmatically from an tableviewcell with the following function.

```swift
private func switchView(identifier : String){
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier) as UIViewController
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
     }
}
```

After a while I need to switch back to the original state, so I call switchView with the same view again. The only problem is that a lot of stuff stays active in the previous ViewController.

How can I dismiss the previous ViewController with all of its contents?

Comment: When you want to go to previous view just check identifier and use pushviewcontroller instead of present.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling 'dismiss' on the VC that you are trying to get rid of?

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
let vc = FirstController()
pvc?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
})
```

[Found this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43566414/present-a-controller-dismiss-it-and-present-a-different-one-in-swift)

Comment: should be noted that this code will go back to `FirstController` and then present `FirstController` on top of itself. causing the user to have 2x `FirstController` in the viewController stack.

Comment: @Vollan That is not what I want. I want to navigate back from FirstController to a new Fresh FirstController.