# Calling a popup after dismissing a VC

Tags: swift, swift3

I am trying to dimiss a VC and then show a popup with an error

I first tried:

```
            case .failure(let error):
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            self.presentMRAlertOnMainThread(title: "Something went wrong", message: error.rawValue, buttonTitle: "Ok")
```

Then I tried:

```
            case .failure(let error):
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
                self.presentMRAlertOnMainThread(title: "Something went wrong", message: error.rawValue, buttonTitle: "Ok")

            })
```

Then I thought it might be an issue with the threads so I tried:

```
            case .failure(let error):
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
               DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.presentMRAlertOnMainThread(title: "Something went wrong", message: error.rawValue, buttonTitle: "Ok")
                }

            })
```

Comment: Your second code looks good as it stands, so what is the issue? What does or doesn't happen? Remember, we don't know what `self.presentMRAlert` is or does or where it lives, so please be informative. Your goal is to make _us_ able to _reproduce_ the issue.

Comment: Are you trying to present the alert on the dismissed VC? If so, that won't work. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43566414/present-a-view-controller-dismiss-it-and-present-a-different-one-in-swift/43566536#43566536

Comment: Hi matt, the present alert is just a popup alert. The issue is I am trying to present the alert on the dismissed vc. It gives error saying: Attempt to present alter for whose view is not in the window hierarchy!