# How to dismiss presented tableview on top of view controller and then instantiate new view controller when row is selected

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I have 3 view controllers - a button on the navigation bar modally presents a tableview from which when you select a row I want to dismiss it and present a new view controller

However when I click the row the table dismisses but doesn't present the new view controller

this is the code from the button to instantiate the second tableview view controller.

```html
@IBAction func gotofriends(_ sender: Any) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Groups", bundle: nil)
    let newVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FriendsList") as! FriendsListToMessage
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.navigationController?.present(newVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

this is my storyboard
.[image]

this is the code for the second view controller to show the third - in the completion block from the dismiss is the code to instatiate a new view controller.

```html
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!
        let username = cell.textLabel!.text ?? ""
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.dismiss(animated: true) {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Groups", bundle: nil)
            let newVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MessageView") as! MessageLog
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.navigationController?.present(newVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

        
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does your program crash or show nothing when you try to present ```MessageLogViewController```?

Comment: it doesnt show anything it just dismisses the second viewcontroller

Comment: Have you tried using a segue from VC2 to VC3 to test if the view controller appears?

Comment: i can segue from vc1 to vc2 to vc3 and it works so im not sure

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43566536/8865491

Comment: Did the post help out?

Comment: hi ive been trying to make it work but its still not working the post didn't make that much sense to me - thanks for sharing it